# How to "unwind" text or shapes that aren't paths?

Tags: animation, adobe-after-effects

Alright, I have a logo that is just a word typed out in a font:

[image]

And I want to do something where the type "draws itself" or unwinds in, like this (wait for the end):

[image]

I know how to use trim paths with curves imported from illustrator, and I can make text in Aftereffects into outlines. But I dont know how to accomplish the "unwinding/drawn in" effect with just type.

The above example has type that is the same width all the way around so it can be a path, but this is not. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Except for the bouncing effect, the rest of the animation could be done using masks, do you know how to use them?

Answer (score -1):

You can reproduce in Illustrator each of the strokes that are part of the characters with simple paths or brushes and replace the last animation frame with the real logo.

- While the animation is on, you don't need the strokes to be perfect replicas of each character stroke
- Even the animation itself distorts the strokes when they are in motion

[image]